# Python datetime unexplained difference between seconds and microseconds

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

What is going on here?

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
# waiting....
>>> b = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> c = b - a
>>> c.seconds
4
>>> c.microseconds
884704
```

How can the microseconds be 2 times more than the amount in seconds? I'd like the precision of microseconds (and then convert it to seconds myself), but this seems simply wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`884704` microseconds means `0.884704` seconds.

```
>>> c = datetime.timedelta(seconds=4, microseconds=884704)
>>> c.seconds
4
>>> c.microseconds
884704
>>> print(c)
0:00:04.884704
```

---

To get total seconds, you can use [`total_seconds()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

```
>>> c.total_seconds()
4.884704
```

Comment: Ah, so I'd have to add them for the total time, how to get the total time, in a floating number of microseconds?

Comment: @Dualinity, Use `total_seconds()` method. I added that.

Comment: @Dualinity, As Tim Pietzcker comment, `total_seconds()` also take account of days.